# Overall sum by groupby pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below, which is area usage of whole city say Bangalore.

```
Sector   Plot   Usage        Status             Area
A        1      Villa        Constructed        40
A        2      Residential  Constructed        50
A        3      Substation   Not_Constructed    120
A        4      Villa        Not_Constructed    60
A        5      Residential  Not_Constructed    30
A        6      Substation   Constructed        100
B        1      Villa        Constructed        80
B        2      Residential  Constructed        60
B        3      Substation   Not_Constructed    40
B        4      Villa        Not_Constructed    80
B        5      Residential  Not_Constructed    100
B        6      Substation   Constructed        40
```

Bangalore consist of two sectors A and B.

From the above I would like to calculate total area of Bangalore and its distribution of usage.

Expected Output:

```
City           Total_Area  %_Villa  %_Resid  %_Substation  %_Constructed  %_Not_Constructed
Bangalore(A+B) 800         32.5     30       37.5          46.25          53.75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need set scalar value to column `city` before apply solution (if there are only sectors `A` and `B`):

```
df['Sector'] = 'Bangalore(A+B)'
#aggregate sum per 2 columns Sector and Usage
df1 = df.groupby(['Sector', 'Usage'])['Area'].sum()
#percentage by division of total per Sector
df1 = df1.div(df1.sum(level=0), level=0).unstack(fill_value=0).mul(100).add_prefix('%_')
#aggregate sum per 2 columns Sector and Status
df2 = df.groupby(['Sector', 'Status'])['Area'].sum()
df2 = df2.div(df2.sum(level=0), level=0).unstack(fill_value=0).mul(100).add_prefix('%_')
#total Area per Sector
s = df.groupby('Sector')['Area'].sum().rename('Total_area')
#join all together
dfA = pd.concat([s, df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (dfA)
           Sector  Total_area  %_Residential  %_Substation  %_Villa  \
0  Bangalore(A+B)         800           30.0          37.5     32.5   

   %_Constructed  %_Not_Constructed  
0          46.25              53.75
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Pivot Table can help!**

**1. One Line Pandas Solution: 80% work done**

`pv =
   df.pivot_table(values='Area',aggfunc=np.sum,index=['Status'],columns=['Usage'],margins=True,margins_name='Total',fill_value=0).unstack()`

**2. Now formatting for %: 90% work done**

`ans =
   pd.DataFrame([[pv['Villa']['Total']/pv['Total']['Total'].astype('float'),pv['Resid']['Total']/pv['Total']['Total'].astype('float'),pv['Substation']['Total']/pv['Total']['Total'].astype('float'),pv['Total']['Constructed']/pv['Total']['Total'].astype('float'),pv['Total']['Not_Constructed']/pv['Total']['Total'].astype('float')]]).round(2)*100`

**3. Adding the Total Column: 99% work done**

`ans['Total'] = pv['Total']['Total']`

**4. Renaming Columns and Arranging in your expected order: and done!**

`ans.columns=['%_Villa','%_Resid','%_Substation','%_Constructed','%_Not_Constructed','Total']`

`ans = ans[['Total',''%_Villa','%_Resid','%_Substation','%_Constructed','%_Not_Constructed']]`